# How to generate 6 phase shifted (60 degrees between each) PWM Signals?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm, microchip

I need to generate 6 phase shifted 5V PWM signals. I need to take a fitting microcontroller (now it is PIC18F66K22 I'm looking for easiest to make (previously I looked at STM32)). I want to know what steps I will/should take to success.
Looking at the datasheet I think it will have 6, 8-bit timers. So I need to figure out how to create phase shifting these PWM outputs for 1/6 period +dead band between each other.

One application imagined has been each signal controlling one transistor of a rectifier.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This is three lines expecting mountains of effort in reply. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic editor here is easy. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of answers it will attract.

Comment: The parts in the STM32 family are quite versatile and many (perhaps all, I didn't check) have more than 6 PWM outputs which are all individually controllable.  So simply program 6 timers with PWM outputs enabled with your required signals.

Comment: Chopin-san - Welcome :-) It's not clear what sort of answer you are requesting. If you are asking someone to recommend a specific STM32 device, then (although some may consider it off-topic) it would help if you can please [Edit] your question to explain your research so far and why devices you found weren't suitable. That way, readers here don't waste time repeating the same work that you have already done. Or are you asking for someone to write suitable code for you? If so, what code have you written and what output was produced? Please read the [tour] and [help] to see what is on-topic.

Comment: The STM32 is not capable of 5 V output, it only has 5 V tolerant input pins.

Comment: I edited question, pls share with knowlegde if you are be able to do so :)

Comment: phase shift in the generation of your PWM signals would essentially translate into time delays, so if your period is time T, if PWM1 goes from state 0(0V) to state 1(5V) at time 0, then PWM2 would do this at time T/2 to attain 180 degrees worth of phase shift

Comment: A look-up table and start reading it on six different points?

Comment: Have a look at Infineon PSoC (4200) MCUs. Some of them have something called Universal Digital Blocks (UDBs). UDBs are programmable logic that can be made into PWMs among other things. Their IDE PSoC creator was impressive when I saw it the first time back when it was still Cypress Semi. Infineon bought Cypress a while back.

Answer (score 0):

The extra 3 phases is unusual, which makes this a harder selection task. However the microcontroller requirements for a suitable inverter are straightforward. You need a system that has 6 center-aligned PWM outputs, all sharing the same time-base, and preferably with complementary outputs.

The time-base requirement is an absolute one for SVM, otherwise the PWM switching phase alignment won't be guaranteed. SVM also requires center aligned PWM generation, so you'll need to check for that option as well. You *may* be able to get away with using two separate timer sources with center aligned PWM, if there is an option to synchronize them and you have a stable shared clock source. STM32 has microcontrollers (i.e. STM32F7) with synchronizable time-bases, and center aligned PWM options.